# Reading an xml file, finding and editing entries, and saving as the original file

Tags: vbscript

I'm loading an XML file into SQL server through a query, the problem is there is a 10x10 table which has a multiple namespace problem. I figured I could solve this with some vbscript, and so far this is the code I have;

```
Dim FSO, FLD, FIL

Dim strFolder

strFolder = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Tests"

Set FSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder (strFolder)


For Each FIL in FLD.Files

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

i=1

Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(FIL)

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

    strLine = objFile.ReadLine

    If i=1 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data1")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=2 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data1")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=3 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data2")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=4 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data2")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=5 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data3")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=6 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data3")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=7 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data4")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=8 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data4")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=9 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data5")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=10 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data5")

i=i+1

ElseIf i=11 and InStr(strLine,"Data")> 0 Then

        strLine = Replace(strLine,"Data","Data6")

End If


    WScript.Echo strLine

Loop

next

When I run this via command prompt:

cd c:\

cscript /nologo Script.vbs >newfile

ren newfile example.xml
```

The file example.xml that is saved is perfect - the center piece of the script with the if then statements does its job right. However, it only works properly if in the folder "tests" I only store one file. If I store more than one file, and use cmd in the same way, it will save all these files back to back. There is about 3,000 files that this needs to be done to, what I would like to do is run the script on each .xml file, then save it as a new.xml with the same name (either overwriting to a new location) in the folder. How would I go about saving them with the same name but with the edit?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is it, some kind of obfuscation contest? I suggest you rewrite your script as follows:

```
strFolder = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Tests"
strFolderResult = "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Tests\Result"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In FSO.GetFolder(strFolder).Files
    i = 1
    Set inFile = f.OpenAsTextStream(1)
    Set outFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(FSO.BuildPath(strFolderResult, f.Name), true)
    Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = inFile.ReadLine
        If InStr(strLine, "Data") > 0 Then
            If i < 12 Then i = i + 1
            strLine = Replace(strLine, "Data", "Data" & i \ 2)
        End If
        outFile.WriteLine(strLine)
    Loop
    inFile.Close
    outFile.Close
Next
```

Comment: Amazing panda-34 it worked perfect, I went off on that tangent likely due to my inexperience with vb.. 
Much appreciated - I also learned a new word